# Return SQL Server column name and corresponding value based on column value

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, excel, pivot

How do I return column name and value based on column value for each record ?

I have this:
[image: I have this]

I would like to update

first_color with color name having highest value

first_value with highest value and so on, as shown in the below snippet.

Note: This is just an example, I have over 100 columns for which I need column name & value for top 5 columns/values. So, looking for a dynamic sql if possible.

[image: I want this]

I got till this point, using cross apply.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SQL Server Approach**

Perhaps with a CROSS APPLY in concert with a ROW_NUMBER()

**Example**

```
Select A.* 
      ,B.*
 from  YourTable2 A
 Cross Apply (Select First_Color  = max(case when RN=1 then Item end)  
                    ,First_Value  = max(case when RN=1 then Value end)  
                    ,Second_Color = max(case when RN=2 then Item end)  
                    ,Second_Value = max(case when RN=2 then Value end)  
                From (Select *,RN=Row_Number() over (Order by Value Desc)
                        From ( values ('Red',Red)
                                     ,('Green',Green)
                                     ,('Blue',Blue)
                                     ,('Black',Black)
                               ) B1 (Item,Value)
                     ) B2
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
unique_id   Red Green   Blue    Black   First_Color First_Value Second_Color    Second_Value
abc12       1   2       4       7       Black       7           Blue            4
mnc23       2   4       1       3       Green       4           Black           3
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that I have over 100 columns for which I would like to get the column name & value. I have downsized it in the example.

Answer (score 1):

With new information, this will unpivot your data without having to to go dynamic.  You can then PIVOT if desired

```
Select A.unique_id
      ,C.*
      ,ColNr = Row_Number() over (Partition By unique_id Order by Value Desc)
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Field = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)')  
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('unique_id')
             ) C
```

Returns

```
unique_id   Field   Value   ColNr
abc12       Black   7       1
abc12       Blue    4       2
abc12       Green   2       3
abc12       Red     1       4
mnc23       Green   4       1
mnc23       Black   3       2
mnc23       Red     2       3
mnc23       Blue    1       4
```